# NFC Antenna Design for ST25R3911B in HFSS: Seeking Assistance with Antenna Parameters Extraction

Tags: inductor, antenna, pcb-antenna, nfc

I am currently working on antenna matching for an ST25R3911B NFC reader IC and using HFSS for simulation purposes. STMicroelectronics provides an antenna matching tool, and I am planning to use a differential antenna tuning configuration for the matching process.

My goal is to design the NFC antenna and simulate it to extract key parameters for proper matching. Specifically, I need to determine:

1. The series inductance and the DC series resistance of the antenna at 1 MHz.
2. The self-resonance frequency (SRF) and the parallel resistance at self-resonance.

This is the antenna I have designed in HFSS from **"X-NUCLEO-NFC05A1 devkit"**
[image: Antenna Designed in HFSS]

I have assigned the material for PCB as "FR4_epoxy". I have also assigned boundary for the antenna along with vias as "PerfE"
[image]

I am confused in setting radiation and excitation ports. Or to say in simple words, "what's after this??"

> Note: I have used **Modal Network** as Solution Type.

It would be great if I can get a proper guidance.

Comment: Have you tried the normal route of contacting [Ansys](https://www.ansys.com) and asking for assistance? Maybe they have forums too?

Comment: I know HFSS has examples for setting up antenna problems. You should follow those examples.